# How was Daniel Lugo able to go to the Bahamas on a boat?

Tags: plot-explanation, pain-and-gain

In the movie [Pain & Gain](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1980209/), How was Daniel Lugo (Mark Wahlberg) able to reach the Bahamas using only a boat?

We can see clearly in the scene where the cops chase Lugo that he jumps into his boat and makes a run for it.

Is it that easy to travel between countries using only a boat with no passports? Is the distance between Miami and the Bahamas really that short?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distance from Miami to the Bahamas is 187 miles.  There are at least two companies that currently offer day trip excursions to the Bahamas by boat.

As for the passport question; since the movie is supposed to take place in 1995 it was perfectly okay to travel to the Bahamas from the USA without a passport at that time.  The rules requiring entry with a passport, trusted traveler card such as NEXUS, SENTRI, or FAST, or an enhanced driver's license weren't put into place until June 1, 2009.

Answer (score 1):

Slight correction to the above answer: It is 187 miles from Miami to Nassau, the capital of the Bahamas. However, it’s 107 miles to Freeport, the second largest city in the Bahamas and there sandbars and cays which are Bahamian territory which are as close to Miami as 80 miles. In a speedboat,especially one like the one shown in the film, that distance can be covered in 1.5 to 2 hours with calm seas.

While do need a passport to land at the ports in the Bahamas, it is an island nation with a small coast guard and police force. If you want to travel there and not be caught there is little to stop you from doing as such.

[Reference:](https://www.google.com/maps/preview?ie=UTF-8&gl=us&daddr=Freeport,%20The%20Bahamas&saddr=Miami,%20FL&panel=1&f=d&fb=1&geocode=KRHByA6isNmIMWVPrd1x8pb_;KZsXyPwb2CaJMX3cyIcDfUI-&ei=oVd5U7uiNI-iyATj94DgBg&ved=0CCUQ5y4&source=newuser-ws)